# Indirect Speech question? She said, "Let's have a beer today."

Tags: grammar

What about this answer? 
She suggested to have/had a beer that day. 
I'm confused between have and had. Please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Peter Shor posted 'I think your answer was not so much incorrect as 100 years out of date. "Suggested to go" would have been fine around 1900.' in response to a [very similar question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124904/suggest-to-go-vs-suggest-going).

> She suggested going for a beer that day.

is one common way of expressing this without using direct speech; another is

> She suggested that we {go / should go / went} for a beer that day.

(All of these latter three alternatives are given by Quirk in ACGEL, and mentioned as being widely used by speakers of standard English by Pullum.)